# update/overwrite feature layer in arcgis.com

Tags: arcgis-online

I'm using arcgis.com to grant access to non-GIS staff.

Using the original table data they provided I published a service with multiple feature layers and spent a lot of time configuring their symbology and behavior in the map viewer.

A week later I was informed that they wanted to add a column to the data and that new records would be added to the original data set as time goes on.

Will I have to recreate everything in ArcMap and republish the service and create a new map feature service or is there a way I can overwrite an existing service so that the feature layer can have new features and attribute table updates but keep the symbology in the current map viewer?